# How to assign string to unsigned char[] in c++

Tags: c++, casting, unsigned

I'm having difficulty understanding typecasting, and i am attempting to improve my understanding by assigning the contents of a `string` to an array of `unsigned chars`. I expected the code below to print `true`, but it does not.

```
unsigned char a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        string b="5";
        if(a[5]==(unsigned char)atoi(b.c_str())){
               cout<<true<<endl;
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It it very, very unclear what you are asking. Are you looking for advice on how to properly compare the contents of a string to the contents of a character array?

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your question to make that more clear?

Comment: And you expect the output to be `true`, correct?

Comment: You never specified in your question. Odds were that was the case, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: @jaggedSpire tank you

Comment: @girl71 ,  the proposed solutions are not suitable?

Comment: @Atomic_alarm   eclipse doesn't resolve **to_string**

Comment: @Atomic_alarm tank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample code has either one or several problems with it if you are attempting to print out `true`. How many depends on how you're trying to do that. **My first two points apply if you are comparing text to other text. If you're trying to convert text to a number and compare numbers, ignore them.**

```
unsigned char a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; // 1
        string b="5";
        if(a[5]==(unsigned char)atoi(b.c_str())){ // 2
               count<<true<<endl; // 3
}
```

1) While this will produce an array of unsigned characters, they won't be text values. The values in that array are the first 10 [ASCII characters](http://www.asciitable.com/) rather than the characters that produce '0' through '9' when printed. Those characters can be placed in your array with the code:

```
    unsigned char a[10]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

Again, this is only provided you're trying to compare text data. If you're trying to convert to a number and compare the entries in this array with that number, you'll want your original array.

2) You are correct that `a[5]` will access the sixth element of `a`. If you are comparing text values and not numeric values, you need only to access the first element of your string for comparison. *This is provided you know the string is at least 1 element in size.* Since you defined it just above this code, that's fine, but in cases of user input, you'll need to check. The proper syntax for this comparison, again as deviantfan stated, is `a[5] == b[0]`, because the `[]` operator on `strings` will return a `char`.

Once again, the above applies to your answer only if you're comparing text values. If you're comparing numeric values, your original code is correct.

3) You haven't placed quotation marks around the `true`. While this will compile, and even print something--it won't be `true` unless a few conditions are met that you're unlikely to encounter this early in your coding career. What you likely meant to put is "true", which will make the output print true. Also, you want `cout`, not `count`.

Here is a [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88aa2cbe706daf35) to an example which compares the string and the (modified) character array, as text data. If you're comparing numeric data, the only thing wrong with your code is 3).

Comment: if sting **b** has more char ,what to do??

Comment: That depends entirely on what you *want* to do. If you're comparing more characters to predefined values, then simply use the comparison between `char` values I outlined above, but with different indices. If you want to compare a string to a number, that's a bit of a different problem, though you can do it in this way. 
If you're comparing more than one character in a row, though, I'd do something else. You can define a character string with `char mychararr[] = "123"` and then use a member function of the `string` class to find that value in a string where you store user input.

Comment: @girl71: This answer is seriously misleading. Your code nearly worked before jaggedSpire made you edit it -- the only problem was that it printed `1` instead of `true`. This is covered in jaggedSpire's third point. But the first two points are quite wrong, in my opinion.

Comment: @TonyK She wanted it to print 'true'. Are you stating that she wanted to convert a string into a number, and compare the number?

Comment: Well, that's certainly what her code _did_, before you broke it.

Comment: My apologies, @girl71, it appears I was mistaken regarding what you wanted for your code. The example I provided compares characters storing textual data, and you wanted to compare them after converting one to numeric data. I will edit my answer to specify that the first two parts of the answer only apply to someone wishing to compare textual data, unless TonyK prefers I delete this answer. TonyK? –

Comment: That is up to you, jaggedSpire! You fixed your mistake, that's the important thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you´re sure that your string `b` has exactly one char:

```
char c = b[0];
```

That´s all.

`atoi` does not extract chars, but parses the numeric content to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be better to convert to a string for comparison:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    unsigned char a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::string b="5";
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<(std::to_string(a[4])==b)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<(std::to_string(a[5])==b)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/9cvce4